# Сделать EditText который позволяет написать только один любой emoji icon или один любой символ

Tags: java, android, kotlin, emoji

**Условия:** Есть приложение, содержащее EditText.

**Задача:** Сделать EditText, который позволяет вписать в себя только один любой Emoji icon или какой-нибудь один символ.

**Идеи:** Я пробовал прописать в параметрах EditText `android:maxLength="1"`, но в таком случае некоторые emoji просто не пишутся. Предполагаю, это происходит потому, что некоторые emoji состоят из нескольких других emoji, которые в последствии объединяются, то есть они имеют длину больше одного символа.

**Вопрос:** Как осуществить задуманное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Удалось реализовать без дополнительных библиотек:**

Создаём Boolean переменную `editTextFlag`, которая используется для того, чтобы пресекать бесконечные изменения текста в EditText, вызванные в результате команд `MyEditText.setText(...)`. (*Дальше станет понятнее зачем нужна эта переменная.*)

Ставим на EditText улавливатель изменений текста (ввода или удаления) командой `.addTextChangedListener(...)`. В нём по дефолту находится три функции: `afterTextChanged`, `beforeTextChanged` и `onTextChanged`. Нам понадобится только одна: "`beforeTextChanged`", которая вызывается за момент до того, как введётся текст.

- `s` - в данной функции это текст, который был в EditText до изменения
- `after` - количество символов в EditText после изменения

В "`beforeTextChanged`" я создал три условия:

1. `(editTextFlag && after == 0)` - вызывается когда пользователь удаляет символ или emoji, то есть количество символов в EditText после изменения равно 0
2. `(editTextFlag && HabitIconEditText.text.isNotEmpty())` - вызывается, когда в EditText уже есть какой-то символ или emoji icon и пользователь пытается добавить ещё один. Мы ему это не позволяем и пишем в EditText текст, который был до изменения, то есть текст `s`, командой `MyEditText.setText(s)`. Ну и для красоты перемещаем курсор EditText в конец строки командой `MyEditText.setSelection(s.length)`.
3. Ну `else` вызывается когда не подходит ни одно из вышеперечисленных условий. В данном случае оно просто переключает переменную `editTextFlag` обратно на true. Дело в том, что при вызове команды `.setText( ... )` `addTextChangedListener` вызывается второй раз. Так как при первом вызове `editTextFlag` переключилось на false, то нужно вернуть эту переменную обратно на на true, делается это как раз при втором вызове, в этом условии `else`.

**Вот собсна сам код:**

```
var editTextFlag = true
MyEditText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher
    {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int)
        {
            when
            {
                (editTextFlag && after == 0) -> {
                    editTextFlag = false
                    MyEditText.setText("")
                }

                (editTextFlag && HabitIconEditText.text.isNotEmpty()) -> {
                    editTextFlag = false
                    MyEditText.setText(s)
                    MyEditText.setSelection(s.length)
                }

                else -> {
                    editTextFlag = true
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}
    })
```

Answer (score 5):

Используйте [Emoji Compatibility](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat) support library.

```
<android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiEditText
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   setMaxEmojiCount="1" />
```